# How do I return the result from promise to map function

Tags: javascript, node.js, rethinkdb

I have a javascript promise where I want to return the value to map function that  Easier to see than explain the problem with second promise. I know I can not return value from inside of promise but i ask if there any better solution to that. Thanks

My code:

```
const _                 = require('lodash')
    Boom                = require('boom'),
    When                = require('when'),
    User                = require('../../models/user');

var users;
/**
 * Contact core functionality
 */
users = {


    /**
     * Find user by id
     *
     * @param       {id} user id
     * @returns     {Promise(User)} User
     */
    findById: (id) => {
        if (_.isEmpty(id)) {
            return When.reject(Boom.badRequest('User id missing.'))
        }
        return User.get(id).run().then( (user) => {
            if (user) {
                return When.resolve(user)
            }
            return When.reject(Boom.notFound('No user registered with provided id.'))
        }).error((error) => {
            return When.reject(error)
        });
    },

    /**
     * Returns all contacts of user from database
     * @returns     [{Promise(Contact)}] contacts
     */
    findContacts: (userId) => {
        if (_.isEmpty(userId)) {
            return When.reject(Boom.badRequest('User id missing.'))
        }
        return User.get(userId).run().then( (user) => {
            if (user) {
                if(_.isObject(user.contacts)){
                    user.contacts = _.map(user.contacts, (contact) => {
                        this.findById.then((user) => {
                            contact.user = user
                        })
                        return contact
                    })
                    return When.resolve(user.contacts)
                }
                return When.reject(Boom.notFound('No contacts registered with provided user.'));
            }
        }).error((error) => {
            return When.reject(error)
        })
    },
}
```

And the issue here:

```
                user.contacts = _map(user.contacts, (contact) => {
                    this.findById.then((user) => {
                        contact.user = user
                    })
                    return contact
                })
```

Comment: Use `Promise.all` on an array of promises.

Comment: @Bergi could you give me an example with my code. Many thanks

Comment: Don't use lodash map. Use when's map. `when.map(array, yourFunction).then(resultsArray => { /* tada */}`

Comment: @Wainage the issue that "yourFunction" it's an promise

Comment: user.contacts = _map(user.contacts, (contact) => {
                        this.findById.then((user) => {
                            contact.user = user
                        })
                        return contact
                    })

Comment: You want the contacts attached to the user as an array of users?

Comment: each contact have user_id i wants to get full object user from this id using first promise above findById

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the When promise library, you should use its own iterators, such as `map` and `reduce`, to process your arrays.

One thing that is incredibly important to note here though is that in When `map` runs "opportunistically" (runs everything at once in parallel) while `reduce` runs in serial with no overlaps. In other words, if you have an array of 1000 users, `map` will (probably) send 1000 requests to your database at once, while `reduce` won't finish until it has completed each database request in turn.

So your code might look like this:

```
// This mutates user.contacts, so you don't need to worry about the
// 'initial value' in your reducer function
When.reduce(user.contacts, (carry, contact) => {
     return this.findById.then((user) => {
         contact.user = user
     })
 });
```

If you do have a ton of users to process, it might make more sense to chunk your data into an array of smaller, reasonably sized arrays; you would `reduce` the chunks and `map` the users in each chunk. This would mean the array could be processed much faster than when done in serial, but without any risk of hosing your database.

**edit**

```
// This mutates user.contacts, so you don't need to worry about the
// 'initial value' in your reducer function
// It also returns the array of users as `allContacts`
var allContacts = When.reduce(user.contacts, (carry, contact) => {
     return this.findById.then((user) => {
         contact.user = user
         carry.push(user);
         return carry;
     })
 }, []);
```

Comment: I'm getting this error this.findById is not a function I thing because findById it's an promise

Comment: If you are using an arrow function, `this` should be what it was outside of the promise (or rather, outside the arrow function itself). Find out what `this` is and proceed from there. If you want a quick resolution, use a closure variable (`let scope = this;` ... `scope.findById().`)

Comment: if(_.isObject(user.contacts)){
                    return When.reduce(user.contacts, (carry, contact) => {
                        return users.findById(contact.user_id).then((user) => {
                            contact.user = user
                        })
                    })
                }

Comment: Yes, the promise should return nothing (you could add `return user`). But your `user.contacts` array has been mutated to include the user data. No?

Comment: Yes normally should i get for each contact user data but after i do                     When.reduce(user.contacts, (carry, contact) => {
                        return users.findById(contact.user_id).then((user) => {
                             contact.user = user
                        })
                    })
                    console.log(user.contacts).                                                            I dont get user data! any solution

Comment: I have updated the answer. Note that `contact.users` and `allContacts` will contain the same data. I'm not sure why you would need the same info twice.

Comment: I need just each contact with his user data so i could return this result. after i tested you edited solution i get carry.push is not a function

Comment: because i use this users.findContacts("c6f4285e-a34a-4790-b125-0135a8b980e3").then((contacts) => {
                console.log(contacts);
            })
i dont get any thing

Comment: Sorry I forget initial array after that { state: 'pending' }

Comment: Based on your last comment (sorry, I deleted my last two comments because they were in error). You definitely need to read the [documentation](https://github.com/cujojs/when/blob/master/docs/api.md#whenreduce) on When's array iterators. Basically, if you see `{state: 'pending'}` it means you are looking at the promise, not the resolved/rejected value. I can't see how you would see that *inside a `then`*. Maybe throw your entire code up on a fiddle.

Comment: With the map it work                     return When.map(user.contacts, (contact) => {
                        return users.findById(contact.user_id).then((user) => {
                            contact.user = user
                            return contact
                        })
                    })

Comment: but with reduce always i got undefined

Comment: Andrew what you suggest?

Comment: Not sure what to suggest. Make sure that your reduce method is getting what it needs. `return When.reduce(array, handler, initialValue)`. And make sure that your handler is getting what it needs: `function (carry, current) { /*do something to mutate carry and then...*/ return carry; }`